# About the dot (.) operator of c#

Tags: c#, struct, static, enums, static-methods

Sorry about the last post...here is another one.

So far I've seem people use the (.) operator to :

(1) access member of structure

(2) access static/constant member of a class

(3) access literal of a enum-type

(for example, those of dayofweek.cs http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dayofweek.cs)

**without having object/instance of that structure/class/enum** .

I know that an operator's meaning can depend on its operand;

but some of them looks kind of weird to me.

For example, in the case of (3):

In C#, I can write:

`DayOfWeek a;
if (a == DayOfWeek.Sunday) *do something...*`;

but in C, I can only write:

`DayOfWeek a;
if (a == Sunday) *do something...*`.

For another example, in the case of (1):

In C, only after we have an instance of a structure can we do operation to its member;

but in C#, just like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888864/two-things-about-source-code-of-struct-datatime-in-c-sharp, we can directly use NAME(i.e., `DataTime`) of a structure to access its member(i.e., `Maxticks`), i.e.,`DataTime.Maxticks`

There obviously is some difference, right?

Where can I read the thorough tutorial or doc of this operation, saying what how I can use this operation? Only the language spec?

**I actually don't appreciate the way learning that by looking through examples using this operation one-by-one, because they don't tell me "how to use it", but just "what I can do with it"; these two are different, though.

Comment: Read up on the static keyword.

Comment: I suggest that you read the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) section [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's all about scope... [instanceName].[instanceMember], [ClassName].[StaticMember], [EnumName].[EnumMember], this.[CurrentInstanceMember] - the left-hand side defines the scope, the . basically always means "inside the left-hand scope" and then the right-hand side is what part of the scope you're trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, the `.` operator is used to access a member.

If that member is marked `static`, then you can reference it via class name, since there is only ever one static "instance" of a class (and it is instantiated by the runtime). That is what your are seeing with `DateTime.MaxTicks`.

Enums are not `static` but their members are accessed the same way, because you need to **qualify** the member name with the enum name. From the C# spec (v 5.0, section 14.3):

> From all other code, the name of an enum member must be qualified with
>   the name of its enum type. Enum members do not have any declared
>   accessibility—an enum member is accessible if its containing enum type
>   is accessible.

One of the uses of `.` is to qualify something (like when you explicitly declare which namespace a class is coming out of).

Basically, you use `.` whenever you want to access a member of something. As long as you know if it is an instance or static variable, you'll know if you need an instance of the type or if you can just use the class name. `.` can also be used to qualify the name of something, which is used when specifying a namespace for a class or using an enum.

Comment: "Enums are not `static` but their members are accessed the same way" this is kind of where my problem is...where can this rule be found?????

Comment: @J.C. added some stuff about the '.' operator being used for name qualification, and the relevant portion of the specification that notes this is required for enums. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you again!! After I posted the comment I looked at examples doing enum variable assignment and read that such qualification is necessary. Also I tried to generate the same situation in C and I  failed; C doesn't allow such situation(i.e., giving different enumeration's member the same name), while C# does. Nonetheless, it seems that in C# this qualification(in enum member accessing) is THUS necessary EVEN NOT IN SUCH SITUATION, and here may be kind of trade-off of lang design here!

Comment: @J.C. I won't pretend to understand the language designers, but I like explicitly saying which enum my value is coming from. It makes the code much more explicit in what it is doing and is easier to read. Regardless, I'm glad I was able to help your understanding!

Comment: Thank you for your consistent feedback Bradley.NET! It's just me forget to click on that mark. Whatever, I think it should be important and helpful for me to practice more on reading language spec and looking things up there in a right way.

Comment: @J.C I'm not sure *I* would ever read the language spec (dry much?) but have fun ;) Unless you have a question like this about the actual syntax of the language, I would go to MSDN first (and I might go there first even for a syntax question). Regardless, I'm glad I was able to help and that you got your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

> In C, only after we have an instance of a structure can we do
>   operation to its member;
>
> but in C#, just like in Two things about source code of struct
>   DataTime in c#, we can directly use NAME(i.e., DataTime) of a
>   structure to access its member(i.e., Maxticks), i.e.,DataTime.Maxticks
>
> There obviously is some difference, right?

We can use the name of class and then dot and the method we want to call, when the method of the class is a `static` method. In this case the method belongs to the class and not to the objects we create using the new keyword.

From the C# specification:

> A method is a member that implements a computation or action that can
>   be performed by an object or class. Static methods are accessed
>   through the class. Instance methods are accessed through instances of
>   the class.

One of the best explanations about the `static` keyword can be found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

As for the access of the members of a `struct` in C#, you use the same operator you use to access the members of a `class` in C#, the dot operator. This is the reason, why you need `DayOfWeek.Sunday`.

Comment: Thank you very much... but for the DayOfWeek part, DayOfWeek is a enumeration, not a class; where can I find a official doc saying that "Sunday", one of seven values of an enumeration DayOfWeek, can be retrieved using `DayOfWeek.Sunday`? After all, this seems not to be allowed in C?

Comment: @J.C. you welcome dude. The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx provides the documentation you are looking for. Please let me know, if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! According to people's feedback to me and my recent experience, MSDN is where a C# programmer(especially for beginner like me) can get lots of info and treasure about the language. The point is how to use it! For this question, the real one might be on: archive-member accessing scope, disambiguous resolution and qualification.

Comment: @J.C. you welcome dude. Yeah for sure, in general terms MSDN helps a lot (not only beginners, believe me). You will find the way of learning from it. That's a personal thing.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as navigating the namespace. Your project structure could be:

- MyApp

  - Forms

    - MainForm

      - ShowForm()
      - IsOpen()
  - Classes

    - SomeClass

      - SomeStaticMethod()
      - NonStaticMethod()
    - OtherClass

      - SomeEnum

        - EnumValueOne
        - EnumValueTwo
  - Repositories

    - ThisRepo

All of this would be called, imported, or accessed a similar way using dot notation despite their different purposes and structures. Calling the static `ShowForm()` void on MainForm would be `MyApp.Forms.MainForm.ShowForm()`, just like referencing an enum in `OtherClass` would be done like `MyApp.Classes.OtherClass.SomeEnum.EnumValueTwo`.

You obviously won't need to do the full qualifying namespace when you add a `using` statement to your class, but hopefully this shows the concept.